# Github actions- Java with maven: mvn verify multiple poms

Tags: java, maven, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

[image: project structure]

This is my project structure. The blue folder have their respective poms in their subfolders.
My question is, in following maven.yml how can I do mvn verify on all those poms? as I have to provide pom location after mvn verify command.

Note- This whole project structure is under a folder named 'web'. Hence you can see in mvn verify command that pom location is under 'web' folder.

[image: maven.yml]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a multi-module project and the subprojects are correctly added as modules in the `pom.xml`, then your command should work.